# Computer cache - data removing

Tags: terminology, computer-architecture, cpu-cache, memory-hardware

I am programming **CPU cache simulator** and I am supposed to implement removing of entries. I will not use LRU but just random.

I am not really clear, when should I call the removing function? When cache *(2 or 4 caches)* are full and CPU wants to write into cache where all *(data and tag)* of specific indexes are same? Are there some other possible situations, or maybe I am completely wrong?

Hope you understand my question, if no, please tell me and I will edit my question. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cache lines are evicted :

- When the OS requests it, it may occur for example in non cache-coherent systems when a peripheral does a DMA transfer (direct transfer from a peripheral to main memory), or if the CPU is shut down to save its state to RAM...
- When all the ways of the cache are already used for the requested line.

In a write-through cache, new data can be directly loaded, overwriting previous contents. In a write-back cache, if the cache line was modified, it must be written back before loading new data.

There could be other exceptional cases, for example if a parity error is detected and new data must be loaded...
But, generally, caches are filled but never emptied.

Comment: You forgot about coherence invalidations (remote writes), but I think the question was asking about when the *replacement* policy is applied (which, of course, happens on a insertion/cache miss).

Comment: @paul-a-clayton : Oh, yes indeed ! Forgot that. S,E->I in a MESI cache...

Answer (score 2):

The simple (possibly, overly simplified) answer is that you need to remove entries whenever a new entry is to be written to the cache, but the cache is full.

That is, if there is a memory access which is a miss and the record is brought to the cache from the main memory, but there is no place to put the new record (all possible places *for that record* are full), you need to make some room by removing one of the records.

Of course, you should write the record(-to-be-removed) back to the main memory before removing it form the cache, and obviously, you should remove a record that resides in the cache in a place that can be used to place the new record. Note that the cache needs not be completely full -- whatever happens in entries where the new record cannot be mapped to is irrelevant.